# How can I add all siblings of the current selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$('div').add($(this).siblings());
```

I want to animate the siblings simultaneously.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to add the siblings to the jQuery object or to the `<div>` element itself?

Comment: Prehaps explain what are you trying to do a bit better.

Comment: if there are more than one <div>s then you might want to use some other selector in the beginning.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to use `.addBack()` to get both the div *and* its siblings. In jQuery versions earlier than 1.8, you should use `.andSelf()` instead, which is now just an alias for `.addBack()` (thanks Sable).

```
// jQuery 1.8+
$("#myDiv").siblings().addBack();

// jQuery <1.8
$("#myDiv").siblings().andSelf();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/addBack/
- http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/

Comment: Great. I always used x.parent().children()

Comment: `andSelf()` has been deprecated and is now an alias for `addBack()`.  See http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/

Answer (score 0):

This maybe?

```
$('div').add($(this).siblings('*'));
```

Answer (score 0):

for animation you can use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and for adding the siblings please specify whether you want to add the siblings to the jQuery object or to the  element itself?